# Xamarin Override RemoteControlReceived in Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, dependency-injection

I am trying to override the RemoteControlRecieved method of the UIApplication and getting the following error:

NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: There can only be one UIApplication instance.

I understand the issue but have not idea how to solve it. I have a StreamingService class which implements the UIApplication and IStreaming interface. All of my AVPlayer functionality is in this class. the StreamingViewModel class calls the

```
DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Play().
```

When this line is called I get the above error. I am not sure how to override RemoteControlRecieved from either the StreamingService or the StreamingViewModel class.

any help with code samples is greatly appreciated.

Classes below

```
public class StreamingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool DisplayPlay { get => !isPlaying; }
    public bool DisplayPauseStop { get => isPlaying; }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    bool isPlaying;
    bool IsPlaying
    {
        get => isPlaying;
        set
        {
            isPlaying = value;
            // Notify the property has changed
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayPlay");
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayPauseStop");
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Play();
        IsPlaying = true;
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Pause();
        IsPlaying = false;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Stop();
        IsPlaying = false;
    }

}
```

Class StreamingService

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(StreamingService))]
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StreamingService))]

namespace test.iOS
{
    public class StreamingService : PageRenderer, IStreaming
    {
        AVPlayer player;
        bool isPrepared;
        string dataSource = "https://stream.voxx.pro/radio/8260/radio.mp3";


        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StreamService ViewDidLoad");
            base.ViewDidLoad();


        }

            public StreamingService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StreamService Default Constructor");

        }


        public void Play()
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Play");

            if (!isPrepared || player == null)
                player = AVPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(dataSource));


            //Audio player Notification in lock screen  
            MPNowPlayingInfo nowPlayingInfo;
            nowPlayingInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo();
            nowPlayingInfo.Artist = "Radio Caravan";
            nowPlayingInfo.Title = "Join The Caravan";

            // Register for receiving controls from lock screen and controlscreen  
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = nowPlayingInfo;

            //var command = MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared;
            //command.PlayCommand.Enabled = true;
            //command.PauseCommand.Enabled = true;


            //command.NextTrackCommand.Enabled = false;
            //command.PreviousTrackCommand.Enabled = false;


            isPrepared = true;
            player.Play();

            base.BecomeFirstResponder();

            //To listen changes in lock screen  
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();

        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            player.Pause();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            player.Dispose();
            isPrepared = false;
        }


        public override void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent theEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remote Control Received");
            base.RemoteControlReceived(theEvent);

            if (theEvent.Subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Pause");
                player.Pause();
            }
            else if (theEvent.Subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Play");
                player.Play();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MainPage.cs

```
    namespace test
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private StreamingViewModel ViewModel { get { return (StreamingViewModel)this.BindingContext; } }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);

            BindingContext = new StreamingViewModel();
        }

        // Callbacks to images tapped
        private void Play_tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.Play();
        }

        private void Pause_tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.Pause();
        }

        private void Stop_tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.Stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Interface: IStreaming

```
    public interface IStreaming
{
    void Play();
    void Pause();
    void Stop();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: There can only be one UIApplication instance.

You could custom **[PageRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers)** to override **RemoteControlReceived** method to check whether it works. Because this will use the existing `UIApplication`.

About `isPlaying` property, you could use [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to define in CustomPage.

About `Play/Pause/Stop` method, you could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send Message from Forms to **CustomPageRenderer**.

For example, part code of **CustomPage** as follows:

```
public partial class CustomPage: ContentPage
{
    public CustomPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsPlayingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsPlaying", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomPage), null);

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value); }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "PlayControl", "Play");
        IsPlaying = true;
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "PlayControl", "Pause");
        IsPlaying = false;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "PlayControl", "Stop");
        IsPlaying = false;
    }

}
```

The part code of **CustomPageRenderer** as follows:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace XamarinForms20.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
         
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //...

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "PlayControl",  (sender, arg) =>
            {
                if(arg == "Play")
                {
                    //...
                }else if (arg == "Pause")
                {
                    //...
                }else if (arg == "Stop")
                {
                    //...
                }
            });
        }

        public override void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent theEvent)
        {
            base.RemoteControlReceived(theEvent);

            if (theEvent.Subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay)
                player.Play();
            else if (theEvent.Subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause)
                player.Pause();
        }
    }
}
```

===================================Update================================

You could have a try with adding `NSNotificationCenter` in `ViewDidload` method for **AVAudioSession.InterruptionNotification**.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
...
NSObject _notificationHandle = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(AVAudioSession.InterruptionNotification, HandleNotification);
...

private void HandleNotification(NSNotification notification)
{
    // Do something
    NSDictionary userinfo = notification.UserInfo;
    NSNumber number = (NSNumber)userinfo.ValueForKey(new NSString("AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey"));
    int value = (int)number.NIntValue;

    if(value == 1)
    {
        // pause
    }else if(value == 0)
    {
        // countinue to play
        AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried to make some changes to my StreamingService class by implementing PageRenderer which allows the RemoteControlReceived to run, but the player seems to be null every time, any idea how to fix that? below is my class:

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes.

Comment: @SameerJaffer Hi, have a try with using  `AVPlayer player = new AVPlayer(new NSUrl(""));` to generate the instance of AVPlayer to check whether it be null.

Comment: whats happening is that the StreamService class is instantiated twice, once on the PageRenderer and then when the StreamViewModel runs the DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Play(); from the Play method. I tried the  your above line but it would not pause or play. It seems that the on every Play/Pause/Stop image click it is instantiating a new StreamService class.

Comment: OUtput:
2021-01-18 10:52:22.019 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamService Default Constructor
2021-01-18 10:52:22.020 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamService ViewDidLoad
2021-01-18 10:52:24.218 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamingViewModel - Play
2021-01-18 10:52:24.224 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamService Default Constructor
2021-01-18 10:52:24.226 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Play
Thread started:  #7

Comment: Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
2021-01-18 10:52:33.225 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:33.225 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Pause
2021-01-18 10:52:36.593 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received

Comment: 2021-01-18 10:52:36.593 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Play
2021-01-18 10:52:38.800 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:40.311 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:41.670 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:47.837 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:47.837 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Pause
2021-01-18 10:52:48.620 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received

Comment: 2021-01-18 10:52:49.194 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Control Received
2021-01-18 10:52:49.194 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Remote Play
2021-01-18 10:52:54.519 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamingViewModel - Play
2021-01-18 10:52:54.519 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Play
2021-01-18 10:53:05.391 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamingViewModel - Play
2021-01-18 10:53:05.391 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] Play
2021-01-18 10:53:20.521 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982] StreamingViewModel - Play
2021-01-18 10:53:20.522 JoinTheCaravan.iOS[15230:5923982 Play

Comment: Sorry I miss-typed earlier:
The StreamingService class is only instantiated twice, once on the PageRenderer and the other when the DependencyService.Get<IStreaming>().Play(); is run. is there a way to make available or pass to the player to the first instance?

Comment: @SameerJaffer If you have use `PageRenderer`, why need to use `DependencyService`? You could use `MessagingCenter` to invoke method from `ContentPage` or `ViewModel`.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your help, I was able to use your example to make it work. I removed the DependencySerice and used MessagingCenter. Another question. the app stops when a call comes in, is there a way to resume after the call?

Comment: Would you have any code examples on how to implement audio resume on Call Interrupt?

Comment: @SameerJaffer You could add `NSNotificationCenter` to continue to play when call end. I have updated the answer but not testing it whether it works, you could have a try. If works let me know that.

Comment: @SameerJaffer If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Will try today and let you now. Does this and the RemoteControll work for Android also? if not what is the equivalent in Android?

Comment: @SameerJaffer No, only for iOS, all codes in iOS solution. If you need andorid, you could create a new question to ask for help. I am not familiar with this for android.

Comment: Hey Junior, I tried your Notification code and it hangs the app as soon as I get a call on. I've added comments in the HandleNotification but never see them in the output.

Comment: I get this error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at JoinTheCaravan.iOS.StreamingService.HandleNotification (Foundation.NSNotification notification) [0x00029] in /Users/sameerjaffer/Projects/JoinTheCaravan/JoinTheCaravan.iOS/StreamingService.cs:124
  at Foundation.InternalNSNotificationHandler.Post (Foundation.NSNotification s) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSNotificationCenter.cs:48
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native)

Comment: UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.8.0.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
  at JoinTheCaravan.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/sameerjaffer/Projects/JoinTheCaravan/JoinTheCaravan.iOS/Main.cs:18

Comment: The NSNumber number variable is null, the AVAudioSessionInterruptionType needed to be AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey value. its working now!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @SameerJaffer Glad it works! Yes, it should be `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey`, I also have modified the code of answer.  If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.